# How to run this program, dump_video.py?

Tags: python, video, python-2.7

I want to run this program, http://pymedia.org/tut/src/dump_video.py.html
It converts video file to image files. I've installed all the modules. When I execute it by run in Python IDLE, it prints Usage... same stuff at the end of the program. My video file is in .avi, xvid codec, says it supports it on page pymedia. I believe that program and my file arent connected, but how to input my file (test.avi) to the program? I put the video file in same folder as program. Says something at the end of the page http://pymedia.org/tut/index.html, to put in cmd, and I did but i keep getting the same message about Usage. Its in the if statement at the end of the file. I worked a little in python, but never with functions, so please help.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `dump_video myvideo.avi myvideo_%d.bmp RGB=2`?

Comment: i wrote that in cmd in folder where's the file and program, and it says 'dump_video' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file, and then i changed dump_video to dump_video.py and got an value error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'RGB=2'

Comment: thanks! its working, only needed 2 instead RGB=2, and it needs .py extension at the end of file. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The [source code](http://pymedia.org/tut/src/dump_video.py.html) contains this Usage message:

```
print 'Usage: dump_video <file_name> <image_pattern> <format_number>\n<format_number> can be: RGB= 2'+\
    '\n<image_patter> should include %d in the name. ex. test_%d.bmp.'+ \
    '\nThe resulting image will be in a bmp format'
```

Per the comments, `dump_video.py` can be called this way:

```
dump_video.py myvideo.avi myvideo_%d.bmp 2
```

This will attempt to save the frames in myvideo.avi into BMP files of the form myvideo_%d.bpm where `%d` will be replaced by numbers. I'm not sure what the last argument, the so-called "format number", `2` does.